# Return the "sub-levels" within column B for each level of column A in R

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, apply, spread

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
  number  fruit status
1      1  apple   ripe
2      2  apple rotten
3      3 banana   ripe
4      4 banana rotten
5      5   pear   ripe
6      6   pear rotten
7      7  apple   ripe

 data.frame(number = 1:7,
       fruit = c(rep(c("apple","banana","pear"), each = 2),"apple"),
       status =c(rep(c("ripe", "rotten"),3),"ripe"))
```

I would like to loop over "fruit" and return the levels of "status" for each fruit. That is, get out something like this:

```
 $apple
 [1] ripe rotten

 $banana
 [2] ripe rotten

 $pear
 [3] ripe rotten
```

It doesn't have to be a list; I just need to know the levels within each "fruit" level. My data is more complicated than the example so assume I can't just remove the "number" column

I am trying to use apply functions or dplyr and I can't figure out how to get this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1) tapply/unique** Assuming only unique values of `status` are wanted this base R solution could be used:

```
with(DF, tapply(as.character(status), fruit, unique, simplify = FALSE))
```

giving:

```
$apple
[1] "ripe"   "rotten"

$banana
[1] "ripe"   "rotten"

$pear
[1] "ripe"   "rotten"
```

**2) split** If it were known that the sublevels of each level are already unique then this base R solution would be sufficient and gives the same result.

```
with(DF, split(as.character(status), fruit))
```

**3) table** Another form of output that might be useful is a table showing the number of occurrences of each sublevel within in each level.  Again this uses only base R.

```
m <- table(DF[-1])
m
```

giving:

```
        status
fruit    ripe rotten
  apple     1      1
  banana    1      1
  pear      1      1
```

We can create a bipartite graph of this using the igraph package:

```
library(igraph)
g <- graph_from_incidence_matrix(m)
plot(g, layout = layout_as_bipartite)
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Nice answer! Am I right that the `with(DF ...` just saves you from writing `DF$` before `status` and `fruit`?

Comment: This is beautiful! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
split(as.character(df$status), df$fruit)

$apple
[1] "ripe" "ripe"

$banana
[1] "ripe" "ripe"

$pear
[1] "ripe" "ripe"
```

Or if you want to keep only unique values:

```
lapply(split(as.character(df$status), df$fruit), unique)
```

Or if you just want to see the values per fruits, then you can try this `dplyr` possibility:

```
df %>%
 group_by(fruit) %>%
 summarize(type = paste(status, collapse = ", "))

  fruit  type        
  <fct>  <chr>       
1 apple  ripe, rotten
2 banana ripe, rotten
3 pear   ripe, rotten
```

Or the same but taking into account only unique values:

```
df %>%
 group_by(fruit) %>%
 summarize(type = paste(unique(status), collapse = ", "))
```